# Cannot import name 'WordCloud'

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, word-cloud

I am using Jupyter Notebook and trying to build a wordcloud. Turns out there are some issues with the pillow package and the internet is full of talks around it. I was geetting the DLL error initially. I tried a lot of different things and not sure which one worked but right now, I am getting the 'cannot import name' error.

**Some details from Anaconda Prompt-**

```
>python -m pip --version
pip 18.0 from C:\Users\Kritika.Jalan\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)

>python -m pip install wordcloud
Requirement already satisfied: wordcloud in c:\users\kritika.jalan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in c:\users\kritika.jalan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\kritika.jalan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in c:\users\kritika.jalan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pillow->wordcloud) (0.45.1)
```

**Details from Jupyter Notebook -**

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
ImportError: cannot import name 'WordCloud'

import PIL
print(PIL.PILLOW_VERSION)
5.0.0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try running `conda install pillow`?

Comment: But isn't it already installed as per the comments above? Both, version 4 and 5. But I'm anyway trying what you said

Comment: I did that installation and now,
    from PIL import Image
    ImportError: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
    Core version: 4.0.0
    Pillow version: 5.0.0

Comment: Try running this `conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud`  got it from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/wordcloud

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'WordCloud'

Answer (score 24):

Mostly, having a `can not import name error` even after successful library installation, is result of conflict with your local file name and python library name.

Do you have your own python file in your local named `wordcloud.py` ?

If yes, that is causing conflict with `wordcloud.py` in python library.

Simply rename your script.

Thanks

Comment: This did the trick fo rme. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You just need to change your file name that is same to the library name